# Loading Symbols Visual Studio 2012 Message - Infragistics

Tags: visual-studio-2012, infragistics

[image: Loading Symbols Visual Studio 2012]

Loading Symbols message is causing lot of delay in loading my application every time. It is taking close to 1 or 2 minutes to load the application. I tried all possible options in Tools - Debugging, but none seem to work.

Any help in how to handle this ?

Comment: Are the symbols actually found or is it that they are being looked for an not found that causes the delay?  
When running look at the modules window to see what assemblies have symbols loaded.  Do you actually need symbols loaded for all of these assemblies?  As far as handling this you have multiple options, including telling visual studio not to load symbols for specific assemblies.  Perhaps you want to check the Enable Just My Code check box on the General Debugging options.

Comment: Also what is your connection to the internet as visual studio may be connecting to the internet to get symbols though if found they should be cached locally.